# Understanding Hertz

Tags: fft, frequency

This question is in two parts, both related in some way or another.

Suppose I have a signal where the sample rate is 44100 and compute a normal 1D DFT on this signal. The size of this signal is 220500. I need to compute the Hertz for the outputted DFT.

I calculate the bins using the formula below:

```
sqrt(output[i].re * output[i]. re + output[i].im * output[i].im)
```

I then find the maximum number in this vector and compute the following:

```
freq = max * 44100 / fft.size()
```

This then gives me a result of: 4526.84

I don't know, something seems to be wrong here, the duration of the file is `0:05` is this result expected or unexpected? I'm sure I need to take into account the number of seconds, but I was lead to believe that the resulting answer should be that of the sample rate (44100)

Question 2:

Let's suppose I've computed a STFT of this signal of size 256 with an overlap of 128, let's suppose I want to calculate the frequency of each of these segments, or, parts, since this will now effectively be a 2D vector. Do I therefore need to calculate this using the formula above, where the FFT size in this case will infact be 256.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why did you think that the result should be the sample rate?

Comment: @JimClay I don't really know. I just picked this up as an observation. I made a simple mono sine wave at 500Hz and got: 10146.4 as a result.. So need to re-think where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of the frequency of a given bin is correct:

$$
Freq = \frac{binNumber}{numberOfBins}F_s
$$

I suspect that the problem is that you are setting the bin number to the maximum bin power instead of the index of the bin with the maximum power.

Comment: by "index of the bin with the maximum power" do you mean the point where it is in the signal/array and not the number itself?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Mind you, for negative frequencies it is slightly more complex, but I didn't want to introduce that complication.

Comment: How do you mean? This currently isn't working. I generated a 10hz sound file from: http://www.audiocheck.net/audiofrequencysignalgenerator_sinetone.php ... The max index is: 440895 where the size is 441001.. My calculation therefore: `440895 * 44100 / 441001 = 44089.4` So where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Would passing the FFT bins through a window function make any difference here?

Comment: That is the negative part of the tone.  (440895 - 441001) / 441001 * Fs = -10.6 Hz.  Pick the maximum bin that is in the first half of the array.  Ignore the last half of the array, which corresponds to the negative frequencies.

Comment: Thanks, this works for 10hz but for anything above 50hz - Just gives ambiguous numbers.. Is there an algorithm in order to make the formula you gave work for all? I.e. negative parts of the tone?

Comment: (441001-440895)*44100/441001 = 10.600 - That sounds reasonably close. Maybe for some reason (implementation?) you took the second peak in the spectrum. An FFT spectrum of a real signal will be conjugate symmetric about it's middle.

Comment: @user7358 Hey, thanks! What do I do for the spectrogram though? For example, in the spectrogram I calculate `10 * log10(sqrt(re * re + im * im)` which calculates the magnitude, right? So can I apply the formula for Htz to the Spectrogram?

Comment: I was trying to point to a flaw in your reasoning. The absolute value of a coefficient is its magnitude, right. This is independent of frequency, however.